# Deleting certain words in a google sheet

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have a few words/ phrases i need deleted from a google sheet quite regularly.
The code will only do 1 word and I would like it to do as many as I need.

```
   function deleteRows() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var s = ss.getSheetByName('Log');
   var r = s.getRange('A:Z');
   var v = r.getValues();
   for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    if(v[0,i]=='Tom')
      s.deleteRow(i+1);
};
```

Comment: In your script, when a value of a cell is ``Tom``, the row is deleted. For this situation, do you want to delete rows including several words you want? For example, when a value of a cell is ``sampleTomsample``, you want to use as the cell including ``Tom``? In order to correctly understand the result you want, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet and the explanation of the result you want?

Comment: HI Tanaike -I need to track the movements of google sheets across 3-5 folders as they move from one folder to another. the export provides dates, movement info. i can delete ANYTHING in C,D & E that doesn't belong to a group that starts with "You moved an item to" . So C10 starts with receiving so the below lines associated in that group (usually its 3 or 4 rows )can be deleted. hope thats explained ok ? thank you https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ty6b48zTb9Yz4iA912jJ44UzUok4uAhsRHE8V5R0iBo/edit#gid=0

Comment: Thank you for replying and sharing the Spreadsheet. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about your question yet. I apologize for my poor English skill. Your shared Spreadsheet has 3 sheets and 4 script files. Can you explain each sheet and script? Can I ask you about the sample sheets before and after the script you want was run? I would like to try to think of about your question using this.